# Filter and Match

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula

I am trying to filter and get the address of the particular value in a field.
[image]

So I need to write a formula to featch the address of each child with age of 0.5 for each year.

I tried FILTER function, but I am not able to use that output array into another formula.

Please help me with this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Edit the post with your attempt of `FILTER()` and the expected results.

Comment: You want the cell address?  No idea why and don't know how to do it with multiple values - this will return the address of the first found value though: `=LET(Result, XLOOKUP(0.5,$B$2:$B$9,$B$2:$B$9), RowNum, ROW(Result), ColNum, COLUMN(Result),ADDRESS(RowNum,ColNum))`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming Years are column `A`, Age is column `B` and Name is column `C`.

If you want the entire table, try:

```
=FILTER(A3:C10,B3:B10=0.5)
```

If you want the names of those .5 years who were seen in 2018, try:

```
=FILTER(C3:C10,(B3:B10=0.5)*(A3:A10=2018))
```